# How can I select first array if country not in array?

Tags: php, html, arrays, geoip

I am using the php geoip_country_code_by_name function to serve up different content for different countries from an array which looks like this:

```
<?php

    $content = array(
        'GB' => array(
            'meta_description'  => "Description is here",
            'social_title'      => "Title here",
            'country_content_js'   => "js/index.js",
        ),
        'BR' => array(
            'meta_description'  => "Different Description is here",
            'social_title'      => "Another Title here",
            'country_content_js'   => "js/index-2.js",
        ),
    );

?>
```

How can I check if the users country is in the array and if not set 'GB' as the default?

I am using this to check for the country:

```
$country = ( isset($_GET['country']) && !empty($_GET['country']) ? $_GET['country'] : ( isset($_SESSION['country']) && !empty($_SESSION['country']) ? $_SESSION['country'] : ( isset($_COOKIE['country']) && !empty($_COOKIE['country']) ? $_COOKIE['country'] : geoip_country_code_by_name(ip()) ) ) );
```

Comment: Maybe you should consider [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: Well, it depends on how you are checking if the country isn't in the array, one way would be to use a ternary operator.

Comment: I'm not sure how to check if the country isn't in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First :  i Added a new variable for default country code .. ($defaultCountry = 'GB');

Second : try to get the country code from (get , session , cookie ,
geoip_country_code_by_name or default as assigned).

Finally :  check if the country code exists in the $content array() otherwise return the default country ..

```
 $defaultCountry = 'GB';
if(isset($_GET['country']) && !empty($_GET['country'])){
    $country =$_GET['country'];
}elseif(isset($_SESSION['country']) && !empty($_SESSION['country'])){
    $country =$_SESSION['country'];
}elseif(isset($_COOKIE['country']) && !empty($_COOKIE['country'])){
    $country =$_COOKIE['country'];
}elseif($value = geoip_country_code_by_name(ip())){
    $country = $value;
}else{
    $country = $defaultCountry;
}

if(isset($content[$country])){
    $country =$content[$country];
}else{
    $country = $content[$defaultCountry];//Default ..
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried using this method and its giving me this error message: "illegal offset type on line 4" ... line 4 is where I have $content = array( GB +> array(country array in here) )

Comment: can you share the ip() function ,so i can give you the full code?!

Answer (score 1):

First check if the country code is in the `$content` array as a key or not, if not serve the first array as a default. To check if the key exists in array or not use **[array_key_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)**.

Like this,

```
$countrycode="IN";
if(!array_key_exists($countrycode,$content)) {
   $countryarray=$content[0];
} else {
   $countryarray=$content[$countrycode];
}
```

Above code will return country's content if available or first if not found in an array.

Comment: This will just check for IN right? I need it to execute for any country that isnt within the array

Comment: Create an array of all the countries and check for each one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with `ternary operator` also

```
countryArr  = array();
$countryArr = array_key_exists($code,$content) ? $content[$code] : $content['GB'];
```